# Combination of Map Container and Structure in matlab

Tags: matlab

i would  like to  visualize  what i will get after concatenation of map and  struct in matlab , for instance let us consider following Map Container

```
ticketMap = containers.Map(...
    {'2R175', 'B7398', 'A479GY', 'NZ1452'}, ...
    {'James Enright', 'Carl Haynes', 'Sarah Latham', ...
     'Bradley Reid'});
```

key/value structure of this map is clear for me, now let us suppose we have  following structure

```
s1.ticketNum = '2S185'; s1.destination = 'Barbados';
s1.reserved = '06-May-2008'; s1.origin = 'La Guardia';
s2.ticketNum = '947F4'; s2.destination = 'St. John';
s2.reserved = '14-Apr-2008'; s2.origin = 'Oakland';
s3.ticketNum = 'A479GY'; s3.destination = 'St. Lucia';
s3.reserved = '28-Mar-2008'; s3.origin = 'JFK';
s4.ticketNum = 'B7398'; s4.destination = 'Granada';
s4.reserved = '30-Apr-2008'; s4.origin = 'JFK';
s5.ticketNum = 'NZ1452'; s5.destination = 'Aruba';
s5.reserved = '01-May-2008'; s5.origin = 'Denver';
```

we have  5 structure  with  different fields, now  following commands

```
seatingMap = containers.Map( ...
    {'23F', '15C', '15B', '09C', '12D'}, ...
    {s5, s1, s3, s4, s2});
```

make sense for me because  for instance using key  23F i can access  fields of s1 structure, for instance

```
>> seatingMap('23F').origin

ans =

    'Denver'
```

all those parts are clear for me, now Using ticketMap and seatingMap together, you can find the name of the person who has reserved seat 15B
ticket = seatingMap('15B').ticketNum;
passenger = ticketMap(ticket)

but is that optimal way?thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.What type of query do you want to perform?

Comment: simple even for  such type of  data,  is  combination of structure and  map container effective?

Comment: It depends. What kind of query do you want to perform?

Comment: at that moment  nothing, but in  the future i wanted to know if i can use it or not

Comment: Yes it is efficient if you want to use it as in your example. But if you want to use a for loop to lookup the hash table for large number of records it may be inefficient.